# Custom getter without return on all paths compiles nevertheless

Tags: kotlin

I wrote this code:

```
var test: String? = null
    get() {
        field?.also {
            return "has value"
        }
    }
```

It reaches `return` only when the field is non-null. Otherwise the body just completes. Nevertheless, this compiles fine and returns `null` if field is null.

If I change to this:

```
var test: String? = null
    get() {
        if (field != null)
            return "has value"
    }
```

now the compiler complains that the block body needs a return statement.

Is this some undocumented feature or a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed [a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-28061), planned to be fixed in 1.3.20.