# While loop nested under synchronized block in Kotlin

Tags: while-loop, kotlin, synchronized

Why the following *does* compile in Kotlin:

```
fun foo(): Boolean {
    while (true) {
        return true
    }
}

fun bar(): Boolean {
    synchronized("") {
        return foo()
    }
}
```

while the following *doesn't*?

```
fun baz(): Boolean {
    synchronized("") {
        while (true) {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

And what is the idiomatic way to make the latter function to compile? I can rewrite it as follows:

```
fun baz(): Boolean {
    synchronized("") {
        while (true) {
            return true
        }

        TODO("Never")
    }
}
```

-- but it doesn't look elegant enough.

Comment: What version of Kotlin are you using?  The `baz` function compiles for me on Kotlin 1.3.

Comment: Whats the error? Seems to compile for me

Comment: @YoniGibbs: kotlinc-jvm 1.2.71

Comment: @EamonScullion: `Error:(8, 5) Kotlin: A 'return' expression required in a function with a block body ('{...}')`

Comment: Looks like this has changed in Kotlin 1.3.  You can try it out [here](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Examples/Hello,%20world!/Simplest%20version/Simplest%20version.kt).  There's an option at the bottom right for what version of Kotlin to use.  Sure enough, it compiles on 1.3.10, but not on 1.2.71.  Can you upgrade your project to Kotlin 1.3?

Comment: @YoniGibbs Thanks, the code does compile on 1.3.10. Will try to upgrade.

Comment: Your issue stems from the same compiler issue that explains [this issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53286435/custom-getter-without-return-on-all-paths-compiles-nevertheless). So Kotlin 1.3 actually has a bug that's in your favor for this example.